# The tag 'Bootstrapper' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:XXX'

Tags: c#, windows-phone, caliburn.micro

I got the following app.xml:

```
<Application 
    x:Class="WeDoneIt.WP2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WeDoneIt.WP2"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And the bootstrapper:

```
namespace WeDoneIt.WP2
{
    public class Bootstrapper : Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Instance = this;
        }

        protected static Bootstrapper Instance { get; private set; }

        protected override void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ShellViewModel>();
            builder.RegisterType<ItemViewModel>();

            base.ConfigureContainer(builder);
        }

        public static T ResolveModel<T>() where T : INotifyPropertyChangedEx
        {
            return (T)Instance.GetInstance(typeof (T), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Why can it not find it?

Comment: It's tagged with wpf but I see `Microsoft.Phone` namespaces... so do you use WPF or WP7 because the bootstrapping is different [see](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation). Otherwise your code looks fine, can you post the full stacktrace? Are your `WeDoneIt.WP2.App` and `Bootstrapper` in the same assembly?

Comment: Fixed the tags and yes, they are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac` package. It states it requires `Autofac (>= 2.6.1.841)` so Nuget will download the latest version which satisfies this decency which is currently `Autofac (2.6.3.862)`. But the `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac` assembly is built against the Autofac version `2.6.1.841` so it won't find the required Autofac dll and fails the build with this cryptic exception.

To solve it: remove all the Autofac and Caliburn related packages and install them in the following way:

```
PM> Install-Package Caliburn.Micro
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1'.

PM> Install-Package Autofac -Version 2.6.1.841
Successfully installed 'Autofac 2.6.1.841'.

PM> Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.Autofac -IgnoreDependencies
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro.Autofac 1.4.1'.
```

How I figured it out: I've created a repro project and installed the `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac` package copied your code and I saw the error message. Then I've removed the bootstrapper init for the app.xaml and added a `var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();` line in the App's constructor in the code behind. Then I've turned on the break on all exception checkbox in VS and I've got a `TargetInvocationException` on the line `new Bootstrapper()` with the inner exception: Could not load Autofac dll version ....

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it was something like that, since I noticed that everything compiled fine when I removed the `ConfigureContainer` overload.